# creating a dashboard for monitoring Kubernetes clusters in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I am trying to create a dashboard for monitoring Kubernetes clusters in Azure for each separate namespace. I would like to have a separate space for each namespace, as well as best practices and cost-optimized tools to achieve this. Additionally, I need to give access to specific users for one namespace and ensure they can only access the dashboard for that namespace's logs.

I am currently using Azure Kubernetes Service and Azure Monitor, but I am having trouble getting started with creating these dashboard. Can someone please help me with this?

I would appreciate any guidance on how to create the dashboard, what tools to use, and any best practices for keeping the costs low while ensuring security and user access control.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

Use Grafana and existing dashboards.

https://github.com/dotdc/grafana-dashboards-kubernetes

https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource/

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to create separate dashboards for each namespace using Metrics Explorer in the Azure portal (Note: You'll not be able to create any alerts on violation thou).
[image]

One of your main requirements of providing access to specific users for one namespace and ensuring they can only access the dashboard is not feasible

The RBAC policy is not very granular to provide access to just the particular dashboard, rather, they might have access to either read or contribute to all the dashboards being created within the scope.

[image]

We found an alternate solution called Serverless360 which helps provide a custom access policy and ensure desired security.

[image]
Providing access only to the specific Dashboard and nothing else, here I have complete control
[image]

We also wanted to create alerts on failure and violations, Serverless360
helped in providing a single consolidated report, reducing the overall cost and manageability of creating multiple alerts, unlike Azure Monitor.